# I need to assign the vaue of fldValue to sipNumber.Where would it be done in my code written below?

Tags: java

Here I need to assign the value of fldValue to sipNumber. How would this be done? Here is the code:

```java
 public static String getCiscoSipPhNo()
     {

         String sipNumber = "";

            Map skillsValueMap = ValidFieldValuesUtil
                    .getValueMap(ADPinEntryAppConstants.AD_PIN_ENTRY_APP_KEY);
            {
                Set<String> keySet = skillsValueMap.keySet();
            for ( String fldKey: keySet)
             {
                if(fldKey!= null && !fldKey.trim().equals("")
                        && fldKey.contains(CsdClient.getLifeCycle()))
                        {
                           String fldValue = (String) skillsValueMap.get(fldKey);
                           break;
                        }
              }
            sipNumber = (sipNumber != null && !sipNumber.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") ? sipNumber : "");
            return sipNumber;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The fidValue is getting assigned to local variable fidValue here.

```
String fldValue = (String) skillsValueMap.get(fldKey);
```

You can make this variable accessible by declaring it outside.

```
String fldValue; // before loop
fldValue = (String) skillsValueMap.get(fldKey);

 sipNumber = fldValue;
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This should work ...

String sipNumber = "";
String fldValue = "";

```
    Map skillsValueMap = ValidFieldValuesUtil
            .getValueMap(ADPinEntryAppConstants.AD_PIN_ENTRY_APP_KEY);
    {
        Set<String> keySet = skillsValueMap.keySet();
    for ( String fldKey: keySet)
     {
        if(fldKey!= null && !fldKey.trim().equals("")
                && fldKey.contains(CsdClient.getLifeCycle()))
                {
                   fldValue = (String) skillsValueMap.get(fldKey);
                   break;
                }
      }
    sipNumber = fldValue;
    return sipNumber;
```